# Модификация (update) c выборкой ( SQL)

Tags: sql

у меня вопрос, который, не могу понять как собрать вместе.

Мне нужно реализовать запрос с изменениями двух значений с выборкой. Уже долго пытаюсь и немогу понять как собрать это вместе.

Я вообще хочу, чтобы получилось так

```
UPDATE ocenka
SET ocenk=0 WHERE ocenk <60  AND ocenk=1 WHERE ocenk >60;
SELECT *FROM ocenka
```

Но у меня не получаеться

Comment: И не получится, что за бред у вас в условии? почему условий сразу два?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы выполнялось два условия. Могу я сделать это последовательно или вместе ака-то ?

Comment: Я вроде понял, нужно два раза прописать update  с значениеми ?

Comment: как по вашему может выполнятся два условия одновременно? меньше 60 и больше 60? число или больше или меньше, одновременно и больше и меньше оно быть не может.
Далее что это за бред? `ocenk <60  AND ocenk=1` вы считаете что 1 может не быть меньше 60?

Comment: UPDATE ocenka
SET ocenk=0 where ocenk <60;
UPDATE ocenka
SET ocenk=1 where ocenk >60;
Так правильно будет ?

Comment: Правильно, но незачем делать 2 запроса, смотрите ответ, там это описано одним запросом

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE 
  ocenka 
SET 
  ocenk=IF(ocenk>60;1;0)
WHERE ocenk!=60;
```

Ровно то что вы пояснили в комментарии, если нужно таки обрабатывать ситуацию для `ocenc=60` - допишите как именно, если нужно исключить из обработки `ocenc=1` - уточните это в комментарии под ответом...